# subset R Characters dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am trying to create a subset from data frame using csv file. The filter to be applied is a character. Here is the code written:

```
project_subset = subset (x = fed_stimulus, subset = 'Project Status' == "Completed 50% or more", select = 'Project Name')
```

The code does not return any error but also does not create a subset. Please help

Comment: You are a first time poster! Congrats and welcome, but we need some data in order to provide you the best solution possible. Can you create a minimally reproducible example?

Comment: See `?subset` probably something like `project_subset = subset (x = fed_stimulus, Project Status == "Completed 50% or more", select = 'Project Name')` will work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason no subset is being created is that with the line

`'Project Status' == "Completed 50% or more"`

you are just comparing two strings which are not equal. This will always be `FALSE`, and subset looks for `TRUE` cases on which to filter.

What you need to do instead is unquote your column name, or pass it through as a data reference.

```
#unquoted variable name
project_subset = subset (x = fed_stimulus, subset = Project Status == "Completed 50% or more", select = 'Project Name')
```

or

```
# quoted variable name but used as a column reference from your original data
project_subset = subset (x = fed_stimulus, subset = fed_stimulus[ ,"Project Status"] == "Completed 50% or more", select = 'Project Name')
```

Answer (score 0):

When the column name has a space you must surround it in back-ticks `` ` ``:

```r
project_subset = subset (x = fed_stimulus, subset = `Project Status` == "Completed 50% or more", select = 'Project Name')
```

However, as the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/subset) states, `subset()` is meant as a convenience function for use interactively, so if you intend to use this in a script it is better to use `[` like this:

```r
project_subset = fed_stimulus[fed_stimulus$`Project Status` == "Completed 50% or more", "Project Name"]
```